# Що таке "джос"?

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія, іменники

Знаю такий фразеологізм **давати джосу**:

> 1. Дуже бити кого-небудь.
> 2. Громити кого-небудь, завдаючи поразки.
> 3. Гостро сварити, критикувати кого-небудь.

У [Словнику мови Стуса](http://slovopedia.org.ua/27/53396/204.html) знаходжу:

> ◊ Дати джосу — дати **поштовх**.

Але чи справді **джос** - це **поштовх**? В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/) цього слова не має.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В [Етимологічному словнику, т. 2, с. 53](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom2.pdf#page=53) знаходимо таке слово із відповідним поясненням:

> **[джос]** (у виразі джосу дати «покара­ти») Кур; - очевидно, пов'язане з ви­разом дати чосу «те.», де ч змінилося на дж внаслідок деетимологізації (пор. та­кож чумак -[джумак], чума -[джу­ма]).

Тобто **джосу** - це **чосу** від слова чесати.

Знову звертаємось в [ЕСУМ, том 6.](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom6.pdf#page=277) і бачимо значення слова чесати:

> **ЧесаТИ** <<ОПОрЯдЖаТИ ВОЛОССЯ; МИКа­ТИ, чухрати; швидко бігти, йти, говори­ти; **бити**, рубати; шпетити•>

Таке ж значення знаходимо у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/chesaty) (3 значення, 3 відтінок):

> **чесати - бити** по чомусь кого-, що-небудь; **дубасити**, **шмагати**. Хлопець.. рушниками зав'язав дякові ноги, потім руки, далі взяв різки, поплював на руки і почав чесати, не дивлячись по чому — по руках, по ушах, по лицю, по колінах (Степан Васильченко, II, 1959, 382).

Отже, **дати джосу = дати чосу = завдати ударів = бити**.